# In c#, how to show specific searched paragraph numbers and docx file name in listview without repeating same file name?

Tags: c#, listview

I am creating an application in which user search word in docx file and get paragraph number which is contained that word. Almost my application work fine but the problem which I was facing is that I get repeating file name and get each paragraph in new listview row. Lets see the image for more understanding.
[Image.](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4BF0A5ABED5ACD5E!554&authkey=!AG1EPmVmOE9BArw&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cjpg)
I just want searched file names and all paragraphs in one row of listview by separate with ','comma. Lets see the desire [image](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4BF0A5ABED5ACD5E!555&authkey=!AEiNef0APALzqgE&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cjpg). 
See Below code which I try

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.listView1.Items.Clear();

        try
        {
            foreach (var filePath in Search(this.textBox1.Text, this.textBox2.Text, this.checkBox1.Checked, this.checkBox2.Checked, this.radioButton2.Checked))
            {
                var file = new FileInfo(filePath);

                this.listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { file.Name, string.Format("{0:0.0}", file.Length / 1024d), file.FullName, toDisplay }));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, string.Format("Exception details:\n{0}", ex), string.Format("Exception '{0}' occurred.", ex.GetType()), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
private static IEnumerable<string> Search(string directory, string searchString, bool searchSubdirectories, bool caseSensitive, bool useRegex)
    {

        /*
         * Below is the list where we insert all paragraph of docx file.
         */
        var paragph = new List<string>();

        /*
         * Below I am using foreach loop by using this I get all docx files from a selected directory.
         */
        foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.docx", searchSubdirectories ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        {
            string docxText;
            int counter = 0;
            using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                docxText = new DocxToStringConverter(stream).Convert();
            string[] lines = docxText.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (line.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show((counter + 1).ToString() + ": " + line);
                    paragph.Add((counter + 1).ToString());
                    arrparagh = paragph.ToArray();
                    toDisplay = string.Join(",", arrparagh);
                    //MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);
                    yield return filePath;
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to move your yield return out of the inner foreach loop. Like:

```
paragph.Clear();
foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (line.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show((counter + 1).ToString() + ": " + line);
            paragph.Add((counter + 1).ToString());
            arrparagh = paragph.ToArray();
            toDisplay = string.Join(",", arrparagh);
            //MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);
        }
        counter++;
    }
    yield return filePath;
```

With your yield return where it is now, it returns out of the function and gets displayed after every line that matches. Moving the yield return out of that inner loop should make it return only after each file has been fully searched.

Comment: I do as you said and I get file name and paragraph no in one row successfully. But when application searches more then one file names which contains same searched words, the previous paragraph nos append with new file paragraph numbers. Here's the image link for your properly understanding [https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4BF0A5ABED5ACD5E!597&authkey=!ADndekjuHJ4hOq4&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg]

Comment: You need to clear out the paragph list at the beginning of each iteration of your outer foreach loop. See edited answer above ^^.

Comment: I want to give a loads of appreciation regarding your cohesive support and thank you once again for helping me.